# How do I open vim from the command-line at a particular tag?

Tags: tags, invocation

I have set up `ctags` to generate a `tags` file for my code base. I can now jump to definitions of functions by running `:tag FUNCTIONNAME` or by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> when my cursor is on the invocation of a function call.

I would like to open Vim or Neovim from the command-line so that it opens the file and navigates to the line number where a function resides, like this:

```
vim --open-tag FUNCTIONNAME
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Good news! This is easy to do. Just use the `-t` command-line option:

```
vim -t TAGNAME
```